# Delete entries of a list nested in a dictionary depending on values located in a different nested list in the same dictionary

Tags: python

I am writing a script to read in a lot of data contained in multiple CSV files. When I read the data from each CSV I put it in a list which is stored in a dictionary so the eventual data structure is:

```
data_set = {user1 : {filenames: [file1,file2...]
                     labels: [file1label_1,file1label_2,file1label_3,file2label_1...]
                     features: [file1feat_1,file1feat_2,file1feat_3,file2feat_1...]
                     file_timepoints: [file1time_1,file1time_2,file1time_3,file2time_1,...]
                     }
            user2 : {filenames: [file1,file2...]
                     labels: [file1label_1,file1label_2,file1label_3,file2label_1...]
                     features: [file1feat_1,file1feat_2,file1feat_3,file2feat_1...]
                     file_timepoints: [file1time_1,file1time_2,file1time_3,file2time_1,...]
                     } 
            }
```

Now the filenames variable is a list of 200 files so the length is 200, but all other variables in the dictionary are lists of length 7000 because they contain data from each timestep of each file.

I am wondering, what would be an efficient way to delete data corresponding to a specific file from all of the lists within a dictionary? So for example if I wanted to delete file1 data for user1 the resulting dictionary would look like:

```
data_set = {user1 : {filenames: [file2...]
                         labels: [file2label_1...]
                         features: [file2feat_1...]
                         file_timepoints: [file2time_1,...]
                         }
                user2 : {filenames: [file1,file2...]
                         labels: [file1label_1,file1label_2,file1label_3,file2label_1...]
                         features: [file1feat_1,file1feat_2,file1feat_3,file2feat_1...]
                         file_timepoints: [file1time_1,file1time_2,file1time_3,file2time_1,...]
                         } 
                }
```

So far I have tried using nested for loops but it gets extremely messy and is highly inefficient. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

[image]

This is an example of what the data looks like. The labels come from a CSV that is just 1 1xNtimesteps row of data, the feature data come from a CSV that is NfeaturesxNtimesteps, and timepoints come from a CSV that is 1 1xNtimesteps row.

Comment: Can you share some data to give us an idea of the format of the CSV? If you're going to be performing any complex operations, you should consider using something like Pandas.

Comment: Your sample data indicates that the values in the 7000 length list are identical to the name of the file? Is that correct, or will it contain the file name?

Comment: I updated the example data to be more representative of the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I think the best way for me to approach this issue would be to use object-oriented concepts, namely using a factory design pattern with classes and an inheritance hierarchy with the files and variables.